# Create a constant tuple with Non-optional values and compare with another tuple which has optional values

Tags: ios, swift, tuples

Basically I wanted to compare two tuples where the `tuple1` has 3 values all are non-optional, and `tuple2` has 3 variables with same data type but all are optional.

```
let tuple1 = (1, true, true) // Static tuple
let tuple2 = (value1?.intValue, value2?.boolValue, value3?.boolValue) //Here value1,2.. are optional `NSNumber` values.
```

when I tried compare them `tuple1 == tuple2`, I was getting compiler error as like below

> Cannot express tuple conversion '(Int, Bool, Bool)' to '(Int?, Bool?, Bool?)'

So I did a work around as like below to clear above error.

`let expectedResult = (LeadSyncStatus.Synced.rawValue ?? nil, true ?? nil, true ?? nil)`

But this time compiler comes with Warning as like below,

> Left side of nil coalescing operator '??' has non-optional type 'Bool', so the right side is never used

How to make the above code executable without compiler error and warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few minutes, I found a work around as like below.

`let tuple1 = (1, true, true) as (Int?, Bool?, Bool?)`

Now the compiler error and warning cleared and code was executed smoothly.

So I thought to share it with everyone.

Hope this might help someone else.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this efficient solution or is there any other efficient way?

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need such a behaviour?

Comment: @FruitAddict, Actually I'm writing Unit Test case, there I needed it. Example: `XCTAssert(tuple1 == tuple2, "test case failed, actualResult:\(tuple2)")`

Comment: Another way to do it: `let tuple1: (Int?, Bool?, Bool?) = (1, true, true)`

Comment: @Jonathan Instead of doing that for every variable he creates, he could just use a struct.

Comment: Another way: `let tuple1 = (Optional(1), Optional(true), Optional(true))`

Comment: @vacawama wow It's nice to see there is lots of way to mark it as optional.

Answer (score 2):

I found another solution and I think this would be better to use than a `struct`: Use a `typealias`

```
typealias tuple1 = (Int?, Bool?, Bool?)

let myOptionalTuple: tuple1 = (1, true, true)

print(myOptionalTuple.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way:

```
let tuple1 = (1, true, true)
let tuple2: (Int?, Bool?, Bool?) = (1, true, true)

let (a, b, c) = tuple2

if let aValue = a,
    let bValue = b,
    let cValue = c,
    (aValue, bValue, cValue) == tuple1 {
    print("Equal")
}
```

---

Or as suggested by [**vacawama**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630618/vacawama)

```
let tuple1 = (1, true, true)
let tuple2: (Int?, Bool?, Bool?) = (1, true, true)

if case let (a?, b?, c?) = tuple2,
    (a, b, c) == tuple1 {
    print("Equal")
}
```